# Avoid autorelease of a NSWindow which is opening another NSWindow?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When I open an `NSWindow` which is autoreleased, everything works correctly. The `NSWindow` is released by my root class only after I've clicked the OK button.

However, when I open an `NSWindow` and from the opened `NSWindow` I open a new `NSWindow`, I get a bad access error. This happens because the first window is not considered active anymore  and it is released by the root class.

How can I avoid this issue ?

Comment: Maybe in Your Attributes inspector is checked "Release When Closed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple answer: don't do this, you are relying on undefined behaviour and asking for a crash. You should hold a strong reference to the window and only release it when you're done with the window.

In general, you should use an `NSWindowController` to manage each window that you open. `NSWindowController` holds a reference to the window and you can easily call the `showWindow:` and `close:` methods of `NSWindowController` to manage window display.

From your question it seems that you are using `NSWindow` objects as window controllers. This is not how you should be using `NSWindow`. Use `NSWindowController` instead, that's what it's for.

Comment: It is clear. Just one thing: what's the proper way to release the NSWindowController from the main document, after you have close its window ? In other terms, I now have a strong reference, but I'm not sure if I should send a notification from the NSWindowController which is closing its window, to the document, to inform the document to release the window controller

Comment: If you think you might display the window again then there's no need to get rid of the window controller. Lazily load it so that it only allocates when you need it, and then just leave it initialized. You can then easily open and close the window. If you must deallocate it, then have your document register for the `NSWindowWillCloseNotification` notification with a nil object, and then when the notification is received, check to see if it's the window controller's window and if so, release the window controller.

Comment: Thanks for the cmplete answer